# Can I parse an OffsetDateTime from an HTML form without asking for the offset?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

I'm trying to receive a date from a JSP form where a user enters a date and time for an event to start. Each event will occur at that instant (i.e. it will be represented by an `OffsetDateTime` object so it can be stored in my DB). It seems to me that my options for getting a date/ time from the user so far are to either use `<form:input type="date"/>` & `<form:input type="time"/>` together or `<form:input type="datetime-local"/>`, neither of which supply the offset necessary to accurately represent the moment the event will occur. Is there a way to gather this offset without explicitly prompting the user for their time zone?

My concern is the following scenario:
A user in another time zone supplies a date & a time for an event. My controller then uses this date/ time to produce a `java.time` object to be stored in the database. However, without knowing what the user's offset is, I have no way to know the correct adjustment to make to the timestamp and it will instead be interpreted as my local time.

Comment: You might be looking [for this](https://attacomsian.com/blog/javascript-current-timezone#:~:text=To%20get%20the%20current%20browser's,UTC%20time%20and%20local%20time.)

Comment: Before you can answer any question to do with dates/times/offsets you need to have a solid understanding of what it is you want to store.  The standard is to store all dates/times as Java `Instant` objects, which uniquely specify an instant in time (in UTC) and apply offsets only in the user interface (i.e. user input and display output).

Comment: @JimGarrison Right, but in order to store that `Instant` I first need to know what time zone the user-submitted information is coming from, no? E.g. if a user in another timezone uploaded an event with a timestamp of 2022-07-13T12:30:00, would I not need to know their offset to properly interpret it? Or are there mechanisms that account for their location and provide the correct UTC of the date/ time they submitted?

Comment: As per my earlier comment, you'll need to use JavaScript in the browser to find the time zone or offset and send it back to the server.

Comment: You can use JS in the browser to determine the client user's timezone.  BUT, you should always display this assumed offset, and also allow the user to give an explicit offset.  The offset field should be prepopulated with the browser's offset.

Comment: Actually, from your description of the problem, it seems that the time zone in which the event will take place might be more use than the time zone that the user is operating in.  In that case, you should definitely provide a way for the user to specify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get an offset from the browser as noted in the Comments.

But really you should **verify the intended time zone** with the user.

[Time zones are named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `Europe/Paris` or `Africa/Tunis`. So you can easily make a hierarchical zone picker.

For critical tasks, such as the user inputting an event to take place at a certain date and time, you should not rely on defaults alone. For example, your user could be a German businesswoman residing in France, currently at a conference in Tokyo Japan, inputting an event to take place in Chicago US. Neither her home time zone, nor her current location will indicate the event is being presented for the time zone `America/Chicago`.

```
String userSelectedContinent = … ;
String userSelectedRegion = … ;
String zoneName = String.join( "/" , userSelectedContinent , userSelectedRegion ) ;
ZoneId z = null ;
try {
    z = ZoneId.of( 
} catch ( DateTimeException e ) {
    … 
} catch ( ZoneRulesException  e ) {
    …
}
```